# Filling out a website form using Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to programmatically fill out a form on a page using Python requests.

I wrote some code to do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests

URL = 'https://www.acgov.org/ptax_pub_app/RealSearch.do'

payload = {
    'displayApn': '1-123-1',
    'showHistory': 'y',
}

s = requests.session()
r = s.post(URL, data=payload)
print r.status_code
print r.cookies
print r.text
```

However, the output isn't coming out as expected.

The status code returned is `200`
The cookies are printing out as `<RequestsCookieJar[]>`
And the text of the response has html headers but it's just a bunch of jumbled up javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="CacheControl" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo="/>

<script>

(function(){
window["bobcmn"] = "111110101010102000000022000000052000000012744f9810200000096300000021application/x-www-form-urlencoded300000000300000006/TSPD/300000008TSPD_101300000005https3000000b008ae96f08bab2000f746485dcaefc4a635c0beff477f241b9355c916986257756d516313dd184676085e51d6fb0a280088bb71708ecac997cbd3b91abf62403b987812f208f2d2cfcb59631333f545e4de4c55cc4d2f00b230000002ashowHistory%3dy%26displayApn%3d1%2d123%2d1200000000";

window.yfma=!!window.yfma;try{(function(){(function(){})();var _s=59;try{var js,ls,Os=S(840)?0:1,zs=S(798)?0:1,sS=S(200)?1:0,SS=S(659)?0:1,_S=S(223)?1:0,LS=S(478)?1:0;for(var OS=(S(787),0);OS<ls;++OS)Os+=(S(125),2),zs+=(S(260),2),sS+=S(567)?2:1,SS+=(S(515),2),_S+=(S(835),2),LS+=(S(127),3);js=Os+zs+sS+SS+_S+LS;window.lJ===js&&(window.lJ=++js)}catch(S_){window.lJ=js}var __=!0;function I(s,_){s+=_;return s.toString(36)}
function I_(s){var _=53;!s||document[l(_,171,158,168,158,151,158,161,158,169,174,136,169,150,169,154)]&&document[L(_,171,158,168,158,151,158,161,158,169,174,136,169,150,169,154)]!==I(68616527613,_)||(__=!1);return __}function l(s){var _=arguments.length,J=[];for(var z=1;z<_;++z)J.push(arguments[z]-s);return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,J)}function j_(){}I_(window[j_[L(_s,169,156,168,160)]]===j_);I_(typeof ie9rgb4!==l(_s,161,176,169,158,175,164,170,169));
I_(RegExp("\x3c")[I(1372146,_s)](function(){return"\x3c"})&!RegExp(l(_s,179,110,159))[I(1372146,_s)](function(){return"'x3'+'d';"}));
var l_=window[L(_s,156,175,175,156,158,163,128,177,160,169,175)]||RegExp(l(_s,168,170,157,164,183,156,169,159,173,170,164,159),I(-41,_s))[L(_s,175,160,174,175)](window["\x6e\x61vi\x67a\x74\x6f\x72"]["\x75\x73e\x72A\x67\x65\x6et"]),O_=+new Date+(S(33)?6E5:615140),Z_,Si,ii,Ii=window[l(_s,174,160,175,143,164,168,160,170,176,175)],Ji=l_?S(99)?3E4:21582:S(85)?6E3:5497;
document[L(_s,156,159,159,128,177,160,169,175,135,164,174,175,160,169,160,173)]&&document[L(_s,156,159,159,128,177,160,169,175,135,164,174,175,160,169,160,173)](l(_s,177,164,174,164,157,164,167,164,175,180,158,163,156,169,162,160),function(s){var _=48;document[l(_,166,153,163,153,146,153,156,153,164,169,131,164,145,164,149)]&&(document[l(_,166,153,163,153,146,153,156,153,164,169,131,164,145,164,149)]===I(1058781935,_)&&s[L(_,153,163,132,162,165,163,164,149,148)]?ii=!0:document[L(_,166,153,163,153,
146,153,156,153,164,169,131,164,145,164,149)]===I(68616527618,_)&&(Z_=+new Date,ii=!1,Li()))});function L(s){var _=arguments.length,J=[],z=1;while(z<_)J[z-1]=arguments[z++]-s;return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,J)}function Li(){if(!document[l(39,152,156,140,153,160,122,140,147,140,138,155,150,153)])return!0;var s=+new Date;if(s>O_&&(S(386)?6E5:758599)>s-Z_)return I_(!1);var _=I_(Si&&!ii&&Z_+Ji<s);Z_=s;Si||(Si=!0,Ii(function(){Si=!1},S(477)?1:0));return _}Li();
var oi=[S(626)?17972802:17795081,S(388)?27611931586:2147483647,S(830)?1862183071:1558153217];function Zi(s){var _=11;s=typeof s===l(_,126,127,125,116,121,114)?s:s[L(_,127,122,94,127,125,116,121,114)](S(475)?36:48);var J=window[s];if(!J[L(_,127,122,94,127,125,116,121,114)])return;var z=""+J;window[s]=function(s,_){Si=!1;return J(s,_)};window[s][l(_,127,122,94,127,125,116,121,114)]=function(){return z}}for(var sI=(S(965),0);sI<oi[L(_s,167,160,169,162,175,163)];++sI)Zi(oi[sI]);
I_(!1!==window[L(_s,180,161,168,156)]);window.Jl={oL:"089e4a9f79017800e36ff59ba1e5d6d5e1f93b16b5b458d18a09540515a45f4c2fa1cb5ea167a407bc42c2be8a0eeaf8c16869b5dd03a199749963ce5b01e899032b244489e7c78f8618c6a53a224b50de13cacbe6346167e00de073de7b15625d0451b8a5cd04cb0895c8cb503536a54c9e0c5e860626b71fc398289ea1aada"};function iI(s){var _=+new Date,J;!document[l(48,161,165,149,162,169,131,149,156,149,147,164,159,162,113,156,156)]||_>O_&&(S(347)?6E5:514364)>_-Z_?J=I_(!1):(J=I_(Si&&!ii&&Z_+Ji<_),Z_=_,Si||(Si=!0,Ii(function(){Si=!1},S(468)?1:0)));return!(arguments[s]^J)}function S(s){return 568>s}
(function(){var s=/(\A([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,6}(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,1}\Z)|(\A(([0-9a-f]{1,4}:){1,7}|:):\Z)|(\A:(:[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,7}\Z)/ig,_=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],J=[];_&&(_=_.innerHTML.slice(0,1E3));while(_=s.exec(""))J.push(_)})();})();}catch(x){
}finally{ie9rgb4=void(0);};function ie9rgb4(a,b){return a>>b>>0};

})();

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/TSPD/08ae96f08bab2000d96246327d838c6fa30bb9c4f41390f6fbd80de23adbed5ac22558a0c0007168?type=7"></script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.<br/>Your support ID is:   183979068942220394.</noscript>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

That's obviously not what I want. I wanna get the contents of the page that renders when I submit the form manually on the browser.

After some browser inspection, when I send the form manually the following request headers are being posted to the server:

```
POST /ptax_pub_app/RealSearch.do HTTP/1.1
Host: www.acgov.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.acgov.org/ptax_pub_app/RealSearch.do
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------5784378851470632262085445332
Content-Length: 304
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: TS744f9810_75=TS744f9810_rc=1&TS744f9810_id=2&TS744f9810_cr=08ae96f08bab280047871c302267d274621ba715eb672bba8c4e6326721d39c4e9275ba2573dd8ecb04e5fd2ed8b14de:08e8846af6032000365890ddfe7c40338b1c71881c3aa160e9b7511f898e727042a17ecd4e549128&TS744f9810_ef=&TS744f9810_pg=0&TS744f9810_ct=application/x-www-form-urlencoded&TS744f9810_bg=08ae96f08bab20007ed7e7334af2c3a0ddc2a737a8f76402a06229c2abec9c180de6732a86a9648608ba63d37c0a28007e212e36225cb10a4cd776ce268b7178b1d33e9bc0271ac4819eb499a739f93571208168c1d71d9c&TS744f9810_rf=https%3a%2f%2fwww.acgov.org%2fptax_pub_app%2fRealSearchInit.do%3fshowSearchParmsFromLookup%3dtrue; _ga=GA1.2.1302812812.1549499581; TSPD_101=08ae96f08bab280047871c302267d274621ba715eb672bba8c4e6326721d39c4e9275ba2573dd8ecb04e5fd2ed8b14de:; JSESSIONID=0000Im6xKN_53mKz4Iw5KNO5gR0:16hgu6tbb; TS01ed31ee=0129191c7e5fb1688bfcca5087fec2a194712c77706b9ba0027f29d8162a79cfc6c4aefe2136c8ca6d34cd2a1622154e5765f831e0e88ce369724f44b0e9f3ebe5c827a6011131434eedec5e04b97f4977a6091f7d; TS01ed31ee_77=08ae96f08bab2800dd88029ca6fb0fa267ec2a5e40e37cef6351b9876c3e34f6bb42cae44bc0afadbb819ab098f6e9b408de561ace82400034a3a6b4be45a224cb4595200fc21d5c6f05b9f72090ad9bf8cf1db9cef92af4944728ce98cc9906ca77cf3a81dbe502fadd7ae968c030f5b7e5f37a743d021e; ASP.NET_SessionId=db12w03jxf5pelnstiyf35jh; _gid=GA1.2.879815811.1551480793
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I doubt my code is sending all of those headers. I'm not even sure what some of them mean or how I could replicate that in my script. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case in your example, but just be aware that if there is CSRF prevention on the form, submitting the data as a POST request like this probably won't work.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Hmm. I'm not quite familiar with the concept. Is there another method that can handle that mechanism?

Comment: A lot of sites have [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection enabled in their forms, which would prevent you from being able to directly POST data to the server that would normally come from the site containing the form. I'm not sure if that's what's happening in your situation, but just wanted you to be aware of it just in case.

Comment: Would there be a different way of approaching that doesn't trigger CSRF? @AndroidNoobie

Comment: I was able to handle this by using Selenium instead and filling out the form data from there with Python.

Answer (score 12):

You are simply missing a single element the site is looking for when you post a request; when you actually use the [intended form page](https://www.acgov.org/ptax_pub_app/RealSearchInit.do), the form includes a submit button:

```html
<input type="submit" name="searchBills" tabindex="9" value="Search" class="btcommon">
```

You need to include that button in your POST data, because it is the presence of that field that the site uses to detect that you made an actual search:

```
payload = {
    'displayApn': '1-123-1',
    'showHistory': 'y',
    'searchBills': 'Search',
}
```

With that one addition, the returned page contains the looked-for search results:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> URL = 'https://www.acgov.org/ptax_pub_app/RealSearch.do'
>>> payload = {
...     'displayApn': '1-123-1',
...     'showHistory': 'y',
...     'searchBills': 'Search',
... }
>>> response = requests.post(URL, data=payload)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
>>> for row in soup.select('#pplresultcontent3 tr'):
...     text = row.get_text(': ', strip=True)
...     if text: print(text)
...
Property Summary
APN: 1-123-1
Property Address: 424 M L KING JR WAY, OAKLAND 94607-3536
>>> for row in soup.select('#pplresultcontent4 tr'):
...     text = row.get_text(' | ', strip=True)
...     if text: print(text)
...
Tax Type | Bill Year | Tracer | Total Amount | Options
Installment | Due Date | Installment Amount | Status/Status Date
Secured | 2018-2019 | 01009500 | $8,773.64 | View Bill | Pay Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2018 | $4,386.82 | Paid Oct 31, 2018
2nd Installment | 04/10/2019 | $4,386.82
```

The history (the `pplresultcontent5` table) is not included until you use a *capital* `Y` for the `showHistory` option:

```
>>> payload['showHistory'] = 'Y'
>>> response = requests.post(URL, data=payload)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
>>> for row in soup.select('#pplresultcontent5 tr'):
...     text = row.get_text(' | ', strip=True)
...     if text: print(text)
...
Tax Type | Bill Year | Tracer | Total Amount | Options
Installment | Due Date | Installment Amount | Status/Status Date
Secured | 2017-2018 | 01009500 | $8,303.42 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2017 | $4,151.71 | Paid Dec 8, 2017
2nd Installment | 04/10/2018 | $4,151.71 | Paid Apr 6, 2018
Secured | 2016-2017 | 01009500 | $7,983.02 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2016 | $3,991.51 | Paid Dec 8, 2016
2nd Installment | 04/10/2017 | $3,991.51 | Paid Mar 30, 2017
Secured | 2015-2016 | 01009400 | $7,864.14 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2015 | $3,932.07 | Paid Dec 9, 2015
2nd Installment | 04/10/2016 | $3,932.07 | Paid Apr 8, 2016
Secured | 2014-2015 | 01009400 | $7,691.52 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2014 | $3,845.76 | Paid Dec 10, 2014
2nd Installment | 04/10/2015 | $3,845.76 | Paid Apr 7, 2015
Secured | 2013-2014 | 01009400 | $7,655.08 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2013 | $3,827.54 | Paid Dec 4, 2013
2nd Installment | 04/10/2014 | $3,827.54 | Paid Apr 9, 2014
Secured | 2012-2013 | 01009400 | $6,102.96 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2012 | $3,051.48 | Paid Dec 7, 2012
2nd Installment | 04/10/2013 | $3,051.48 | Paid Apr 8, 2013
Secured | 2011-2012 | 01009400 | $6,213.30 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2011 | $3,106.65 | Paid Dec 9, 2011
2nd Installment | 04/10/2012 | $3,106.65 | Paid Apr 10, 2012
Secured | 2010-2011 | 01069800 | $5,660.56 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2010 | $2,830.28 | Paid Dec 9, 2010
2nd Installment | 04/10/2011 | $2,830.28 | Paid Apr 10, 2011
Secured | 2009-2010 | 01070300 | $5,917.10 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2009 | $2,958.55 | Paid Dec 10, 2009
2nd Installment | 04/10/2010 | $2,958.55 | Paid Apr 10, 2010
Secured | 2008-2009 | 01070300 | $5,547.66 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2008 | $2,773.83 | Paid Dec 10, 2008
2nd Installment | 04/10/2009 | $2,773.83 | Paid Apr 10, 2009
Secured | 2007-2008 | 01069100 | $5,423.06 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2007 | $2,711.53 | Paid Dec 10, 2007
2nd Installment | 04/10/2008 | $2,711.53 | Paid Apr 10, 2008
Secured | 2006-2007 | 01069000 | $5,387.94 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2006 | $2,693.97 | Paid Dec 10, 2006
2nd Installment | 04/10/2007 | $2,693.97 | Paid Apr 10, 2007
Secured | 2005-2006 | 01069100 | $5,243.04 | View Bill
1st Installment | 12/10/2005 | $2,621.52 | Paid Dec 9, 2005
2nd Installment | 04/10/2006 | $2,621.52 | Paid Apr 10, 2006
Secured | 2004-2005 | 01068900 | $4,855.00 | View Bill
1st Installment | $2,427.50 | Paid Dec 10, 2004
2nd Installment | $2,427.50 | Paid Apr 10, 2005
```