# Scraping aspx in Python

Tags: python, html, web

I want to do web scraping with a web http://m.smv.gob.pe:8082/SMV.OpenData.Web/Views/Datasets/EstResult.aspx, but this web has a table which I want to get the data in hidden.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPl9b.png)

When I go to Inspect I find the table that I want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gcak.png)

But when I do my code, I cannot find that table
This is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msqqe.png)

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you include your code in your question? Not as an image

Answer (score 0):

The table is not present until you fill the entries with the needed data and press the button. Since you don't do that with your code, you are not getting the table. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954231/filling-out-a-website-form-using-python-requests) how you could fill the data with requests.

If is not possible to click the button or fill the entries with requests, you will have to use a package like `scrapy` or even `selenium` in the worst case.

Let's be noted that when the table is present in a webpage from the start (not like your case), you might be able to use `pandas.read_html(URL)` from the `pandas` package and get the present tables as a list of dataframes.